# Where do I set dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath for vscode-dotnet-test-explorer extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have found various documentation stating I need to `dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath`. I can not find that string anywhere, where is it set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer through trial and error.

The settings for the `vscode-dotnet-test-explorer` extension go in the file `.vscode/settings.json`

The extension now finds my tests. My file `settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "APIvNext/UnitTests"
}
```